# How to enter IP address with port into Google Chrome for android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

When I type IP address and port (eg.: `192.168.0.9:15672`) on android google chrome 60, I am redirected to google search on that IP address and port.

I want to access that as URL, not as google search. How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use specific ports in Chrome for Android (and most mobile browsers), you must include the transport protocol as well..

For example (IP addresses are as an example, not valid just news.com):

64.38.232.185:18081 <- will result in a search

http://64.38.232.185:18081 <- will initiate hypertext transfer protocol on port 18081

64.38.232.185:58443 <- will result in a search

https://64.38.232.185:58443 <- will initiate a secure http connection on port 58443

Without specifying the transport protocol, most mobile browsers don't assume, although some browsers do assume common alternative port usage like 8080 or 8443.

So basically, type the full url including specifying the transport protocol prefix (http:// https://) and not just the IP address and port.